# Spring Data Jpa call to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a method that call Stored Procedure to do a very easy insert and a select,

I created a stored procedure on an Oracle database as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.insertNewTable(p_test IN VARCHAR2, p_out OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE("TEST") VALUES(p_test);
SELECT '1' INTO p_out FROM DUAL;

COMMIT;

END;
```

Then on an Entity:

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "insertNewTable", outputParameterName="p_out")
String insertNewTable(@Param("p_test") String p_test);
```

but everytime i call this method i get this:

```
2018-06-23 20:04:43,047|ORA-06550: row 1, colonna 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTNEWTABLE'
ORA-06550: riga 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

2018-06-23 20:04:43,100|org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; SQL [insertNewTable]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:503)
```

After a couple of tries (and exceptions), I modified the Entity and the call to avoid "OUT" types and, in this way, I have no errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.insertNewTable(p_test IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE("TEST") VALUES(p_test);

COMMIT;

END;
```

Then on an Entity:

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "insertNewTable")
void insertNewTable(@Param("p_test") String p_test);
```

How can i fix this to get a return value?

Answer (score 1):

with Spring DATA

in your repository:

1) calling with native SQL :

@Query(value = "select Store-procedure-name(:param) from dual", nativeQuery = true)
    BigDecimal method-name(@Param("param") Long param);

2)

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "store-procedure-name", outputParameterName = "output-param-of-store-procedure")

return-type-of-store-procedure  method-name(input-params-of-store-procedure);
```

Comment: #1 only works for functions, not procedures.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NamedStoredProcedureQuery

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "insertNewTable", 
    procedureName = "insertNewTable", 
    parameters = { 
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name 
= "p_test"), 
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, type = String.class, name 
= "p_out"), 
      )
    }
)
```

method call:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = 
this.em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("insertNewTable");
query.setParameter("p_test", ""TEST"");
query.execute();
String out =  query.getOutputParameterValue("p_out");
```

Comment: I have 2 databases: using this approach, the EM returns always the connection to the @Primary datasource. How fix that? Why my originary code is not working?

Comment: Your suggestion is to add that annotation in the Repository?

Comment: This doesnt't work!! I tried it and I still get the same error!

Comment: none of these work with multiple OUT parameters returned from stored procedure